# Keeping the oldest record in a data extension full of duplicates

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have a data extension full of duplicate email addresses. I would like to keep the Subscriberkey that has a length of 36 over lengths of 64 where there is a duplicate email address.

I've tried the following but I think I'm a long way from a solution:

```
select
c.emailaddress,
case
when c.subscriberkey = c1.subscriberkey then c1.subscriberkey
else c2.Subscriberkey
end as subkey,
c.FirstName,
min(c.createddate) as timestamp
from
contact2 d1 
left join 
(
select subscriberkey, emailaddress from contact2 where len(subscriberkey) = 36
) c1 on d1.emailaddress = c1.emailaddress
left join
(
select subscriberkey, emailaddress from contact2 where len(subscriberkey) = 64
)c2 on d1.emailaddress = c2.emailaddress
group by d1.emailaddress, c.subscriberkey, c1.subscriberkey, c2.subscriberkey, c.FirstName
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you:  I created a DE called Contact1 with a primary key of emailaddress.

```
select
d1.subscriberkey
, d1.emailaddress
, d1.firstname

from
contact2 d1 
Left join 
(
select subscriberkey, emailaddress, firstname  from contact2 
where len(subscriberkey) = 36) C1 ON d1.emailaddress = c1.emailaddress
```

Comment: How will this query find the oldest record, when you don't include the createddate in there?

Comment: Great point @LukasLunow I should have built this into the query as well, sort of took a step back to get the core functionality working and validated before adding the filter to keep the oldest record.